# How to wrap text in autocomplete dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-framework-7

The problem is I already have an autocomplete dropdown (Framework 7) with full of data in my mobile app. But some of them are too long. So I can't see the the full sentence in the dropdown. It is better to have a feature to word wrap in framework 7. But I could't find a way to do that.

```
<div class="item-content">
  <div class="item-inner">
    <div class="item-title label"><b>Product</b></div>
    <div class="item-input-wrap">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Select Product" id="autocomplete-dropdown-all">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using this code segment to render data.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `white-space: normal` on the `.autocomplete-dropdown .list .item-title`.

Comment: I tried out different kind of css attributes regarding white space and word wrap. Unfortunately that didn't work.